# Document view in angular

Tags: angular

How can I code a Document to view in a new tab if it does not support browser then download - using angular

**html**

```
<div class="view-link-content">
    <a (click)="onDownloadAttachment(tableItem)" class="link-text">{{downloadLabel}}</a>
</div>
```

**component**

```
onDownloadAttachment(attachment: IAttachment) {
    const attachmentId = attachment.id;
    const fileName = attachment.fileName;
    this.cleanupAfterDestroy(this.applicationCreateService.getAttachmentContent(attachmentId)).subscribe({
        next: (attachmentContent) => {
            saveAs(attachmentContent, fileName);
        }, error: (error) => {
            this.appController.handleServerErrorMessage(this.componentName, error, CRUDOperation.Get);
        }
    });
}
```

**service**

```
public getAttachmentContent<T>(attachmentId: number): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(`${ApiAttachmentConstants.URL}/${attachmentId}/${ApiAttachmentConstants.FUNCTION_GET_ATTACHMENT_CONTENT}`,
      {responseType: "blob"})
}
```